# Segmentation of 1 Million customer getting slow

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, elasticsearch, amazon-aurora

We are using MySQL Aurora, we have 1 million customers in the customer table and the customer table has around 30 columns.

When the first time we load, we load 50 records with a limit and order by date with the total customer count. This first loading takes approx 60 sec. We also have different segmentation options by which user can filter their data. We have indexed all the important columns that can help us to speed up the filter query. We also tried increasing the server resources but does not see significant changes.

We are looking for a solution that can help to load the records in under 3 sec for the first time and with different segmentation also.

We are open to any solution, and looking for the answer to the following questions:

1. Doest the AWS MySQL compatible Aurora is enough capable of doing this, doest it can support this much faster query with complex filters?
2. Should we plan to sync our data to any other type of database server and load from there?
3. Any suggestion for the database server that is frequent insert/update supported and can query extremely fast records.

Any help on the above point will be really appreciated.

UPDATES:

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id, `c`.first_name, `c`.last_name, `c`.email, `ssh`.`shop_name`, `ssh`.`domain`, `cx`.`is_push_access`, `cx`.`last_contacted_by`, `cx`.`last_email_open_type`, `cx`.`last_email_open_date`, `cx`.`last_contacted_date`, `cx`.`last_email_link_click_date`, `cx`.`avg_order_amount`, `cx`.`email_marketing`, `cx`.`loyalty_email`, `cx`.`newsletter_email`, `cx`.`review_email`, `cx`.`lyt_points_earned`, `cx`.`is_product_reviewed`, `cx`.`is_bounce`, `cx`.`lyt_points_redeemed`, (lyt_points_earned - cx.lyt_points_redeemed - cx.lyt_points_expire) AS `points_remaining`, `cx`.`lyt_is_refer`, `cx`.`lyt_cus_birthday`, `cx`.`lyt_customer_status`, `cx`.`lyt_points_expire`, `cx`.`contact_status`, `cx`.`source_detail`, `cx`.`total_sent`, `cx`.`last_order_date`, `cx`.`utm_source`, `cx`.`utm_medium`, `cx`.`utm_campaign`, `cx`.`utm_content`, `cx`.`utm_term`, `cx`.`total_campaign_sent`, `cx`.`total_campaign_opened`, `cx`.`total_campaign_clicked`, `cx`.`last_campaign_sent_date`, `cx`.`last_campaign_opened_date`, `cx`.`last_campaign_clicked_date`, `cx`.`total_campaign_delivered`, `ca`.`company`, `ca`.`address1`, `ca`.`address2`, `ca`.`city`, `ca`.`province`, `ca`.`country`, `ca`.`zip`, `ca`.`province_code`, `ca`.`country_code`, `ct`.`tier_name`, `aft`.`code` AS `affiliate_code` 
 FROM `tbl_customers` AS `c`
 LEFT JOIN `tbl_shop_setting` AS `ssh` ON c.shop_id = ssh.id
 LEFT JOIN `aio_customer_extra` AS `cx` ON (c.id = cx.customer_id)
 LEFT JOIN `tbl_customers_address` AS `ca` ON ca.id = cx.customer_default_address_id
 LEFT JOIN `aio_lyt_customer_tier` AS `ct` ON cx.lyt_customer_tier_id = ct.id
 LEFT JOIN `aio_customer_custom` AS `acc` ON acc.customer_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN `aio_aft_affiliates` AS `aft` ON aft.customer_id = c.id WHERE (c.shop_id = 'xxxx') 
 GROUP BY `c`.`id` 
 ORDER BY `c`.`last_seen_date` DESC, `c`.`id` DESC 
 LIMIT 20
```

Note:

1. All the foreign keys and GROUP and ORDER BY columns are properly indexed.
2. If we remove the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause, the query executes extremely fast (under 1 sec), but we can't permanently remove that, with GROUP BY and ORDER BY it's taking 45 sec.

Comment: Please show us a couple of the complex filters; we need to work from actual queries; there is not silver bullet at the global level.

Comment: @RickJames - I have updated the question and added the first loading query which takes approx 45 sec. Please check my note too.

Answer (score 0):

**Indexing**

If you don't already have these indexes, I recommend adding them:

```
c:  INDEX(shop_id, id, last_seen_date)  -- in this order
cx:  INDEX(customer_id)
aft:  INDEX(customer_id,  code)
acc:  INDEX(customer_id)
```

(If any is already the `PRIMARY KEY`, don't redundantly add an `INDEX`.)

If that does not help enough, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and move on to...

**Reformulate** to avoid "explode-implode":

What you have gathers lots of data, then GROUPs them and ORDERs them.  Instead, let's turn the query inside out.

1. find the 20 customers.id that are needed -- do this with as little effort as possible.
2. gather all the other stuff needed

Step 1 is probably simply

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  `tbl_customers` AS `c1`
    WHERE  (c1.shop_id = 'xxxx')
    GROUP BY  `c1`.`id`
    ORDER BY  `c1`.`last_seen_date` DESC, `c1`.`id` DESC
    LIMIT  20
```

Note that the index I recommended above will be "covering" for this subquery.

Step 2:

```
SELECT [ lots of stuff ]
    FROM ( [ the above query ] ) AS c2
    JOIN tbl_customers AS c  USING(customer_id)
    LEFT JOIN  [ all the LEFT JOINs, as you have ]
    ORDER BY c.last_seen_date DESC, c.id DESC    -- yes, this is repeated
```

(Note that the GROUP BY and LIMIT exist only in the subquery.)  (I assume that the PK of tbl_customers is customer_id.)